# Controlar nova aba do Google Chrome com Selenium VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome

Estou escrevendo um código para liquidar umas operações num site.
Diretamente do excel, através do VBA, utilizando a biblioteca SELENIUM, escrevi um código para logar e preencher campos com informações diretamente da planilha.
O código vai bem até o momento que ele clica em um campo e é aberta uma nova aba(a aba abriria do mesmo jeito se fosse manual). 
O problema é que quando essa nova aba abre, ela não responde aos comandos do código, que continuam mandando comandos para a aba inicial onde o código começa.
Meu código está assim:

```
Sub Test()
Dim bot  As New WebDriver
Dim login As String, cpf As String, senha As String, comando As String
cpf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 7)
login = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 7)
senha = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(4, 7)
comando = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 7)
bot.Start "chrome", "www.site.com.br"
bot.Get "/"
bot.Wait 1000
bot.FindElementById("abrirModalLogin").Click
bot.Wait 500
bot.FindElementById("cpf").SendKeys cpf
bot.FindElementById("username").SendKeys login
bot.FindElementById("password").SendKeys senha
bot.Wait 500
bot.FindElementById("submit").Click
bot.Wait 500
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='menuPrincipal']/ul/li[4]/a").Click
bot.Wait 400 bot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/header/div[1]/div[3]/nav/ul/li[4]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a").Click
bot.Wait 1000
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso e poderia me informar como continuar mandando comandos para a nova aba aberta.

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com

```
bot.SwitchToWindowByTitle "Title"  'Substitui pelo título exato da nova janela
```

Ou então caso só tenha aberta essa nova janela

```
bot.SwitchToNextWindow
```

**EDIT:**

Aqui está um simples teste para comprovar que o comando `SwitchToNextWindow` alterna para a nova aba:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim bot  As New WebDriver

    bot.Start "Chrome"
    bot.Get "https://www.google.com"
    bot.ExecuteScript ("window.open('http://www.facebook.com/')")
    bot.SwitchToNextWindow
    Debug.Print bot.Window.Title

End Sub
```

Retorna :

```
Facebook - Log In or Sign Up
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Porém este comando alterna entre janelas e não entre abas.
Já tentei este.

Comment: Alterna sim entre abas.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado!
Funcionou!!!